# Qt - how to emit a signal from derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, derived-class

In my custom derived class I'm trying to add and emit a signal gotChange(QString change):

```
#ifndef NETTEXTEDITOR_H
#define NETTEXTEDITOR_H

#include <QTextEdit>

class NetTextEditor : public QTextEdit {
    using QTextEdit::QTextEdit;
public:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) override;

signals:
    void gotChange(QString change);
};

#endif // NETTEXTEDITOR_H
```

Declaration is ok, but when I try to emit it, I get the next error:

> /home/mrsydar/Projects/Qt/DOCSHARE/nettexteditor.cpp:5: error:
> ‘gotChange’ was not declared in this scope
> ../DOCSHARE/nettexteditor.cpp: In function ‘void doEmit(QString)’:
> ../DOCSHARE/nettexteditor.cpp:5:10: error: ‘gotChange’ was not
> declared in this scope
> 5 |     emit gotChange(em);
> |          ^~~~~~~~~

I think that it is because of derivation, but I'm very new to Qt and don't know any alternatives or how to fix this.

```
#include "nettexteditor.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>

void NetTextEditor::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) {
    int key = e->key();
     if((key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57)){
         QString delta;
         int position = this->textCursor().position();

         delta = "c " + QString::number(position) + " " + (char) key;

         emit gotChange(delta);   //if i comment this emit out, everything compiles without errors
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: add `Q_OBJECT` before `using QTextEdit::QTextEdit;`

Comment: @eyllanesc then I get another error: undefined reference to `vtable for NetTextEditor'

Comment: delete the build folder and re-compile

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you. It is working :) You may post an answer and I will tag it

Comment: undefined reference to `vtable` usually means that you need to run qmake (to create moc_*.cpp file for qobject-derived class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create signals or slots then you must use the macro `Q_OBJECT` in the private section. Then you can run "run qmake" (or simply delete the build folder) and compile the application